# Fast, duplicate requests create duplicate records that shouldn't be valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, validation, duplicate-data

There are validations in place that should not allow a duplicate record in a particular table to be created based on two different ID values (one is a user ID) and a state (some states are allowed to have duplicates, but not others).

When we get two requests, one after another in the logs with the same time stamp, the first record is not in the database to cause the rejection of the second record. It is very odd because the two requests are from different IPs, but have the exact same information (maybe a reply attack from a compromised computer?).

We were thinking about creating a unique index on the database, but it won't work since only certain states for records should be checking for uniqueness.

Is there a way we can create a database constraint, validation constraint, requests constraint or something else to help avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: The model seems too complicated, or not normalized enough. You can create trigger constraints or check constraint, depending on the database. Also, it sounds like lack of proper transaction usage -- as the (create) process is not atomic?

Comment: First, the create process spans two different models (including the user). We could probably have nested transactions in that case potentially. Second, we are using MySQL for our database.

Comment: BTW, isn't Base.save automatically transactionally safe? If so, why wouldn't it be working in this case?